# Calculate c so that the following function is a PDF

Tags: probability, density-function

I have this exercise which I don't know if I solved it right:

I have to calculate $c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the following function is a PDF in $\mathbb{R}$.

$
f(x):=\left\{\begin{matrix}
& ce^{-a^2x} & 0<x\\ 
& 0 &  otherwise 
\end{matrix}\right.$ Where $a\neq0$

I have done the following:

$c\int_0^\infty e^{-a^2x}dx=1=\frac{-c}{a^2}[\frac{1}{e^{a^2x}}]_0^\infty=\frac{-c}{a^2}(-1)=> c=a^2$

Is my solution right?

Comment: Yes.  This is an exponential distribution with rate $a^2$